# NTP client are not syncing correctly from same local NTP server

Tags: server, ntp

I am working on Solr cluster setup in Azure VM. 
I created an NTP server on a zookeeper node which is perfectly syncing from STARTUM-1 NTP server.
I configured NTP service on all of my 4-node solr cluster. It is suppose to be sync with the local NTP server (what I configured on Zookeeper node).
They are getting time from there. However while I am checking time on all four NTP client Solr nodes, there seems to be a lack of 1-2 seconds among them despite they are getting time from the local (within same network) NTP server as STARTUM-2.

I tried with **ntpd -gq** for forcefully sync, however even it doesn't helped here.

Can you please guide me to get this fixed.

Thanks a lot
Alok